# fetching json from xcode

Tags: ios

I am calling webservice written in .net from xcode 4.The output is a json string .when The call is made with url   usingstatic ip address it gives error.HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.But works when same url is called in localhost.the code is given below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    NSURL *url=[NSURLURLWithString:@"http:// static ip address where serviceis located(169.254.216.8)/restGroceryService/WebService/insertList?prods=apples,bananas,milk"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *pageSource = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"page source%@",pageSource);
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data  options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSArray *array = [json objectForKey:@"result"]; 
    NSDictionary *store = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    NSNumber *storeId = [store objectForKey:@"storeId"];
    NSNumber *total = [store objectForKey:@"TOTAL"];
    self.priceTextField.text =[total stringValue];
    NSString *storeName = [store objectForKey:@"storeName"];
    self.storNameTextField.text = storeName;
}
```

Comment: Why so many newlines? do you like scrolling that much?

Comment: I think you are using a local IP and you are trying to access it using the 3G network. It won't work. You have to connect to a local wifi or use an extern IP address.

Answer (score 1):

```
ithink the error was here try now:


NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"your address"];/<------ here was the error
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *pageSource = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"page source%@",pageSource);
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data  options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSArray *array = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
    NSDictionary *store = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    NSNumber *storeId = [store objectForKey:@"storeId"];
    NSNumber *total = [store objectForKey:@"TOTAL"];
    self.priceTextField.text =[total stringValue];
    NSString *storeName = [store objectForKey:@"storeName"];
    self.storNameTextField.text = storeName;
```